# Stuck on this linear equation $y'=(3x^2-e^x)/2y-5$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Given this separable equation: $y'=(3x^2-e^x)/2y-5$.

I did integration, I found my constant $c=-3$.

And now I am stuck on this part: $y^2-5y=x^3-e^x-3$.

No matter what I do, I cannot come to this correct answer, according to the textbook, $y=-5/2-sqrt(x^3-e^x+13/4)$.

Comment: How did you find the constant $c=-3$? It doesn't follow from anything you have written.

Comment: Also, you have a quadratic equation for $y$ - what happens when you solve it? Use the quadratic formula, or complete the square --- don't you get pretty much what you want?

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks, used completing the square. Got the right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did it right. Just see that : $$y^2-5y+\frac{25}{4}=x^3-e^x-3+\frac{25}{4}$$ so $$\left(y+\frac{5}{2}\right)^2=x^3-e^x-3+\frac{25}{4}=x^3-e^x+\frac{13}{4}$$ so one solution may arise of a form: $$y=-\frac{5}{2}+\sqrt{x^3-e^x+\frac{13}{4}}$$

Comment: Is this called "completing the square" that they teach in precalculus?

Comment: @BluePonyInc.: Yes. Note that, there is another solution.

Comment: Again, well-done!

Comment: How are we coming up with $(\frac{y+5}{2})^{2}$ from $(y^2)-5y+ \frac{25}{4}$. Shouldn't that be $(y-\frac{5}{2})^{2}$? Which would then lead us to a solution of $y=\frac{5}{2}+(x^3-e^x-\frac{13}{4})^{\frac{1}{2}}$